# Is there a C# equivalent to pythons ast.literal_eval function

Tags: python, c#, arrays, string, decode

Im new to C# and looking for a nice and convenient way to translate an array encoded as a string back to an array in C#. For example, convert the string "[1.2,24.4,35.5,4.5]" to an array of floats

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval("[1.2,24.4,35.5,4.5]")
[1.2, 24.4, 35.5, 4.5]
```

or the string "["foo",123,[1,2,3]]"

```
ast.literal_eval("[\"foo\",123,[1,2,3]]")
['foo', 123, [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Does that count as valid json? You could try `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<float[]>("...")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array of floats you have presented can be interpreted as JSON. You can use JSON.NET or your preferred JSON serializer to deserialize this to an array in C#.

JSON.NET:

```
float[] myArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<float[]>("[1.2,24.4,35.5,4.5]");
```

System.Text.Json:

```
float[] myArray = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<float[]>("[1.2,24.4,35.5,4.5]");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to implement a expression interpreter that more general and more
complex.
You can do it with regular expression and some linq expression.It maybe simplest.
the code as below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace StringToArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string testString = "[1.2, 24.4, 35.5, 4.5]";
            // It rough mean that have some digit and maybe have comma and some digit after comma.that repeat many times.
            var array = Regex.Matches(testString, @"(\d+\.?\d*)+") 
                .Select(group => Convert.ToDouble(group.Value)) // Get digit string and convert to double
                .ToArray(); // Get float array
            foreach (var value in array)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value); // Output: 1.2, 24.4, 35.5, 4.5
            }
        }
    }
}
```